Is there alternative formula for =_xlfn._xlws.SORT($J$3:$M$17,4,1) in excel 2016
I need to to sort data from one table in another Identical table in descending order to procude a chart. Below are the tables
I need an alternative formula to sort
I have tried using =_xlfn._xlws.SORT($J$3:$M$17,4,1) in 2016 but to no avail
Expected results in image

The SORT function was introduced in Excel 2024/365.  There is no SORT function in Excel 2016.

Is manual sort not enough for your task?

If you open up a spreadsheet that you did not create, you may run into the "__xlfn" prefix before certain functions. The generic meaning of xlfn is "unsupported function". Typically, it indicates that the worksheet was created in a newer version of Excel and uses functions not yet available in the version currently running.

There is no built-in formula in Excel2016 for sorting but it is still doable with the help of helper columns.
First, you can use AGGREGATE and SMALL to sort the 4th column of your table in ascending order:
That is, in cell O3, use =AGGREGATE(15,4,$M$3:$M$17,ROW()-ROW($J$2)). (formula can be dragged down).
You will see the numerical values in column M is now sorted from smallest to largest.

The second step is to work out the original position of the sorted numbers.
e.g. the smallest number is 0, we need to know its corresponding row in the original table M3:J17.
If there is no duplicate value in column M, you can use MATCH to find out position. however, in the presence of duplicates values, you will need the help of COUNTIF function together with AGGREGATE function.
Formula in cell P3 is =AGGREGATE(15,6,IF($M$3:$M$17=O3,ROW($M$3:$M$17)-ROW($J$2)),COUNTIF($O$3:O3,O3)). (also drag down the formula).
It is the original position for each number in column O.

Finally, you can display the results using INDEX.
Formula in Q3 is =INDEX($J$3:$M$17,P3,). (drag down the formula).
The results is exactly the same as =SORT(J3:M17,4,1)


If using VBA is permitted
This code does the same as the Sort WorksheetFunction in your issue.
Place it in the sheet's module
Sub sorting()

range("$J$3:$M$17").Sort range("$J$3:$M$17").columns(4),xlAscending

End Sub

